# rails g creates haml file, need erb files to be generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have comfortable-mexican-sofa gem installed for my app. It has haml-rails as its dependency. So when I run rails g scaffold scaffoldname I get files with .haml extension in the view. But I don't want .haml I need .erb files to be generated. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your default template engine as erb.

See the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow) for changes you can make in your `config/application.rb`.